# Yahoo Pipes - How Do I Truncate the last 5 Characters

Tags: url, truncate, yahoo-pipes

I am using Yahoo Pipes to rewrite a URL. Everything is fine but the last 6 characters of the URL need to be removed from all the links.

Ex.

http://www.mysite.com/blahblah/34567

needs to be rewritten to

http://www.mysite.com/blahblah

The number at the end is always changing, so I am hoping to just chop the last 6 characters off of each url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want the [Sub string module](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=string#SubString). Presuming it functions in a similar way to other languages, you'll want an undefined From value, and a Length value of -6, which should cut 6 characters off the end of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that a regex in (.*)(.....) and takinq only the first match should do the trick